# newline in text fields with python csv writer

Tags: python, csv

when parsing rows to a csv file with csv module, if \n is present in field text this will be creating a newline in the resulting csv file.
Consider the following code:

```
import csv

field_names=['id', 'number', 'scope']

data_rows=[
{'id': 100001, 'number': 'a01', 'scope': 'row1 test \n\nrow1 test\n\nrow1 test'},
{'id': 100002, 'number': 'a02', 'scope': 'row2 test \n\nrow2 test\n\nrow2 test'}
]

tbl_name= 'testnewlines'

with open(tbl_name+'.csv','w', newline='',  encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer=csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=field_names,delimiter='|')
    writer.writeheader()
    for d_row in data_rows:
        writer.writerow(d_row)
```

the resulting csv file will be as follows

```
id|number|scope
100001|a01|"row1 test 

row1 test

row1 test"
100002|a02|"row2 test 

row2 test

row2 test"
```

how do I avoid having newlines created in the csv file if \n is within quoted text?
In the footnotes of the module documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html
suggests that newline='' should do, but not in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The created file is a valid CSV file - parsers should be able to identify that a pair of quotes is open when they find a newline character.

If you want to avoid these characters for being able to see then with a normal, non CSV aware, text editor, then you have to escape the newlines, so that the data output is transformed from the real newline character (a single byte with decimal value 10 (`\x0a` or `\n`) ) to two printable character sequence: `\` and `n` (2 bytes with decimal values 92 and 110) - or any other sequence of your choice.

On the Python side, that is simply achievable with a str.replace call. However, although you will then see the CSV data rows in the same "physical TXT data rows", in a similar manner applications that will later *read* this file as data, like a spreadsheet or other Python scripts, won't recognize these sequences as "newlines": you will have to replace them again for newlines after being read (or just keep the modified data and work with it).

```
tbl_name= 'testnewlines'

with open(tbl_name+'.csv','w', newline='',  encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer=csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=field_names,delimiter='|')
    writer.writeheader()
    for d_row in data_rows:
        # the next three lines could be written as a comprehension.
        # I am unwinding them for clarity
        new_row = {}
        for key, value in data_rows.items():
            new_row[key] = value.replace("\n", "\\n")  if isinstance(value, str) else value
            # "\\n" escapes the "\" itself so it is a literal "\" 
            # character, and not a character escaping the "n"
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Just to emphasize with other words: this will create a file that is more neat to look at with a text editor, but will not preserve the recorded data for a round-trip: it will require a custom-step after reading to undo this replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by simply escaping the (`\n`).

Replace this :

```
    for d_row in data_rows:
        writer.writerow(d_row)
```

By this :

```
    for d_row in data_rows:
        writer.writerow({k: v.replace('\n', '\\n') if isinstance(v, str)
                         else v for k, v in d_row.items()})
```

Output (*.csv*) :

```
id|number|scope
100001|a01|row1 test \n\nrow1 test\n\nrow1 test
100002|a02|row2 test \n\nrow2 test\n\nrow2 test
```